# Meaning of 'this' inside jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I am reading an excellent book about jQuery (Apress Pro jQuery) and I am a little confused about the use of 'this'.
For example I am reading the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isResult = $('img').is(function(index) {
        return this.getAttribute("src") == "rose.png";
    });
    console.log("Result: " + isResult);
  });
</script>
```

I am wondering at which object in this case 'this' refers to.
Thank you.

Comment: It's reffering to the selector `$('img')`

Comment: If you want to check it out, you can always open up a console and do `console.log(this)` to see what it's referring to.

Comment: @RPM, 'this' is not referencing the jQuery object $('img'), it is referencing the DOM element.

Comment: @BrianGlaz Unless you have break point inside that function, `console.log(this)` would return `window` object.

Comment: @Vega I meant 'open up a console' so you can view the result. I didn't mean to execute that code from the console. It should be inside the function, of course. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @BrianGlaz : Really great answer!

Comment: @Jack : The most clear answer of all! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` in the "this" context is a reference to the DOM `img` element.

Comment: it's actually the set of objects referred to by the selector, which may contain 0 or more img elements.

Comment: @SamTyson: Actually, the function is ran for *each* `<img>` element, so `this` the individual `<img>` element.

Comment: @SamTyson : Great answer too, the console.log(this) that I used inside the function returned six elements with one of them only with src="rose.png" attribute so the final result of the second console command is true!

Comment: As the book says is(function(index)) --> Returns true if the function returns true at least once.